# Is SpeechRecognizer only available when Android Wear is connected to smart phone?

Tags: speech-recognition, wear-os

I'm using `android.speech.SpeechRecognizer` and it only seems to work if it's connected to the paired phone via Bluetooth. If I disable the phone's Bluetooth, `SpeechRecognizer` will stop working. This holds for being paired with both an iPhone or with an Android phone. Is an active phone connection really a constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Checking on the documentation, it looks like it can still be done by just using the system's SpeechRecognizer activity.

You just need to call the `startActivityForResult` with the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` set, which will start the Activity and return the data thru `onActivityResult`

```
private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

// Create an intent that can start the Speech Recognizer activity
private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    // Start the activity, the intent will be populated with the speech text
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
}

// This callback is invoked when the Speech Recognizer returns.
// This is where you process the intent and extract the speech text from the intent.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        // Do something with spokenText
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Can you please point me to the documentation that states that we only need a Bluetooth connection if we use `SpeechRecognizer` directly?

Comment: My aim is to actually not use the system activity (as it would leave our UI) and to recognize speech within our app.

Comment: [Here's the [training documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#FreeFormSpeech) I was referring to. It defines the System-provided voice actions as task-based and built in to the wear platform itself. I believe this is what you may need to recognize speech within the wear app itself.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm afraid that this video doesn't answer my question whether I can use SpeechRecognizer only with an active Bluetooth connection.